# nginx not working at all

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, wsgi

I try to set my server according to https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html.
So my uwsgi works well. but nginx doesn't show me media files when i try to open 127.0.0.1:8000/media/1.jpg (my test file), and seems that it doesn't work at all. Error log file is empty. Don't have any idea what to do now and how can i find the problem.

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/django/momstyle/momstyle.sock;
}

server {

    listen      8000;
    server_name         momstyle-kzn.ru; 
    charset     utf-8;


    client_max_body_size 75M;


    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/momstyle/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/django/momstyle/static; 
    }


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/django/momstyle/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
```

i have a link on this file in etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.
i set static roots and media root correctly in my setting.py file. When i run only wsgi by
    uwsgi --http :8000 --module my_site.wsgi
everything works well. Please give some advices on how to solve this problem or how can i find possible reason of this problem. Thanks!